# Firebase: import and export Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I need to know how to export and import files from my Storage to another firebase,  project, the problem is that I have searched in forums and I cannot find how to perform this operation in firebase

thanks for everything :3

Comment: Your first paragraph is actually one very long sentence that's hard to understand.  Could you edit the question and clarify what it is that you need to know that's not clear from the documentation?

Comment: Are you asking now about how to copy files from Cloud Storage buckets between projects?